# Не получается отфильтровать массив по диапазону дат на js

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 2 переменные, дата начала и дата конца.
И мне нужно отфильтровать мой массив в данном диапазоне.

```
const startDate = "Sat May 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
const endDate = "Tue May 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
```

Массив который нужно отфильтровать

```
const allArr = ["Mon May 04 2022 17:35:27 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 07 2022 17:49:18 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 09 2022 17:49:25 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 13 2022 17:49:33 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 14 2022 17:49:43 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"]
```

Пробовал сделать так, но это не работает:

```
     allArr.filter((date) => {
        date = new Date(date)
        return date => new Date(startDate) && date <= new Date(endDate)
     })
```

Comment: Какая ошибка выскакивает?

Comment: @4500zenja ошибок нет, просто возвращается целый массив, не отфильтрованный. Т.е те же самые 5 элементов

Answer (score 1):

Результат работы функции [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) является **массивом**, т.е. его нужно куда-то сохранять после его применения. Исходный массив при этом не изменяется (да и не может, ибо `const` стоит), отсюда и отсутствие изменений.

```js
const startDate = "Sat May 07 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
const endDate = "Tue May 10 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"
const allArr = ["Mon May 04 2022 17:35:27 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 07 2022 17:49:18 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 09 2022 17:49:25 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 13 2022 17:49:33 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)", "Mon May 14 2022 17:49:43 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)"]
const result = allArr.filter((date) => {
  date = new Date(date)
  return date >= new Date(startDate) && date <= new Date(endDate)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!)

Comment: @vasiluey1992 Не забывайте отмечать правильный ответ галочкой, пожалуйста